# Wordpress Custom Field (Advanced Custom Field plugin) URL value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Rookie question here.

I have 2 images with URLs (facebook and instagram) on my site. I found the 2 custom fields (avdanced custom field plugin is installed) in Field Groups. The Default Value of both fields is empty however the URL values must be set somewhere, as both images are clickable. Where can I change these values?

Here is the code:

```
while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="social">
                        <a href="<?php the_field('inst');?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/inst.png" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="<?php the_field('fb');?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/fac.png" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
```

Are the values being set somewhere within the code?

Comment: Nope, your code is pulling the data from the database so check in your admin Dashboard again. These fields must be in there somewhere, maybe as theme options?

Comment: Found nothing that relates to these 2 fields, checked also the Themes. In every page I have the code I pasted. However still can't find where I can change the URLs of these custom fields.